# How can I store a class object with a dictionary into neo4j?

Tags: neo4jclient

I need to have a dictionary in class.
Now I want to save the class object into neo4j by neo4jclient(i'm using c#)
But it seems something wrong.
I always get the error "MatchError: Map() (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapper"
Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Neo4j store a dictionary in a node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132187/can-neo4j-store-a-dictionary-in-a-node)