# How to add properties of node dynamically using Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to add Lable and properties of Node dynamically using Neo4jClient
I try to solve it like following code,but it doesn't work.

```
        client.Cypher
                 .Create("(person:Type)")
                 .WithParam("Type", "Vegetable")
                 .Set("person.property= \"zhai\"")
                 .WithParam("property", "name")
                 .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

my Model is

```
class Data
{
        public Data()
        {
            properties = new Hashtable();
        }

        private string type;

        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set { type = value; }
        }

        private Hashtable properties;

        public Hashtable Properties
        {
            get { return properties; }
            set { properties = value; }
        }

    }
```

I want to import the properties of Data into properties of node.
Thx Z.Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first off, `Neo4j` doesn't support `Dictionary` elements (like a `Hashtable`) by default so you're going to need a custom serializer, such as the one in this question: [Can Neo4j store a dictionary in a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132187/can-neo4j-store-a-dictionary-in-a-node)

Knowing this, you *can't* set the values in the `Properties` `Hashtable` the way you are trying to. It's *not* possible.

So now that's out of the way, let's have a look at the `Cypher`.

So, cypher wise - I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, *BUT* I think something like this is what you're after:

```
var data = new Data{Type="Vegetable"};
data.Properties.Add("name", "zhai");

client.Cypher
    .Create("(person {personParam})")
    .WithParam("personParam", data)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

That will put the node into the database, *however* you will *not* be able to query by any value in the `Properties` property.

I think you should spend a bit of time reading the Cypher manual to understand what it is you're trying to do, as I think that will get you a lot further.

Comment: Thanks, Chris~,it is very useful